# QgsField - addAttributes

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgsvectorlayer

I'm constructing new memory layer to do some spatial data processing. I opened new `QgsVectorLayer` and I'm trying to add fields dynamically using

```
fld = QgsField("Name", typeName = "TypeName")
```

Constructing a list of fields with a loop based on information from other layers.

When I call:

```
layer.dataProvider().addAttributes([list of QgsField])    
layer.updateFields()
```

and then to check :

```
print("Layer init fields:", [field.name() for field in layer.fields()])
```

I get empty list, which means there are no initialized attributes in a layer.

My question is `QgsField` correctly initialized?

```
res = layer.dataProvider().addAttributes(field_def_list)
print("Adding attributes...:",res)
```

Says it is initialized. Any idea where I abused the `QgsField` init.
Is initializing `QgsField` by `typeName` right way to go defining new fields or should I use `QVariant.Type`?

Comment: See here for working code : https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/tests/src/python/test_provider_memory.py#L403

Comment: Thanks for overview. Nice piece of code !!

Answer (score 1):

So to answer my own question, `QVariant.Type` has to be defined if you want to construct `QgsField`. Defining `typeName` doesn't work.